# Is my SSD broken/faulty?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, bios, sata

I basicaly have a situation where i cannot access a SSD (SATA) drive at all. And i was wondering if it is broken or not.

I bought the SSD in 2020 and I thought I installed Ubuntu on it, but I am not sure anymore. It was still connected to a machine I was not using due to homeoffice situation. But it did not show up when I booted the machine.

I investigated and I could not see it in bios either. I changed the storage mode to AHCI (from IDE), and I also changed the cables and connected outlets on the mainboard. Another disk works fine on the same cable/outlet. But it still is not recognized in bios.

As I cannot remember if I ever used the SSD, at least not a lot, it would be shame if I should throw it out. Is there anything else I should do to determine if the disk is broken?

Comment: Why 2010? It only mentions 2020

Comment: Sorry, mixed up with another post. 2020 is much too soon for it to fail.

Answer (score 2):

If you connect your SSD to a SATA connector that is addressed directly by the mainboard chipset and it does not show up in BIOS your SSD is broken.

Sometimes boards come with additional chips whose functions are not available during boot time, only after the operating system has loaded an additional driver. Connecting your SSD here is unsuitable for diagnosis.